# Can kernel schedule user level threads of same process on different cores?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

As far as I know kernel doesn't know whether it is executing a user thread or user process because for kernel user threads are user process, it only schedules user processes and doesn't care which thread was running in that process.

I have one more question, Is there per core ready queue or a single ready queue for all the cores?

I was reading [this](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/linux:osdi10.pdf) paper and it is written that

> In the stock Linux kernel the set of runnable threads is partitioned
>   into mostly-private per core scheduling queues; in the common case,
>   each core only reads, writes, and locks its own queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux kernel scheduler uses the "task" as its primary schedulable entity. This corresponds to a user-space thread. For a traditional simple Unix-style program, there is only a single thread in the process and so the distinction can be ignored. Other programs of course may have multiple threads. But in all cases, the kernel only schedules tasks (i.e. threads).

Your terminology above therefore doesn't really match the situation. The kernel doesn't really care whether the different threads it schedules are part of the same process or different processes: each thread can be scheduled independently. You can have multiple threads from the same process running on different processors/cores at the same time.

Yes, there are separate run queues for each core.

The paper you reference is, I think, slightly misleading in its phrasing. In particular, saying that the "set of runnable threads is partitioned into..." doesn't give quite the right meaning; that makes it sound like the threads are divided into multiple groups that are then assigned to different cores and can only be executed there. It would be more accurate to say that there is a separate run queue for each core containing a set of threads waiting to execute, and in common use, the scheduler doesn't need to reference the queues for other cores.

But in fact, threads can migrate from one core to another. For example, if there is a thread waiting to run on core A (hence in core A's run queue), but core A is already busy running some other thread, and there is another core that is not busy, the waiting thread may be migrated to that other core and executed there. (This is an oversimplification of course as there are other factors that go into deciding whether/when to migrate a thread.)